# Haskell: Writing text files and parsing them back to original format

Tags: file, parsing, haskell

I have a list of tuples of format [(String,String)] and I need a function to write the contents of the list to a text file, then another function to read this text file in as the same list of tuples. Here's what I've got for the saving function:

```
save :: Table -> IO()
save [] = writeFile "database.txt" ""
save zs = do { writeFile "database.txt" "" ; sequence_ [appendFile "database.txt" ("("++a++","++b++")\n") | (a,b) <- zs] }
```

Would that be a good format for the text file? Then how would I be able to read that text file in and convert it back to the list of tuples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defined in `Prelude`,

```
type ShowS = String -> String
class Show a where
    showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS
    show :: a -> String
    showList :: [a] -> ShowS

type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
class Read a where
    readsPrec :: Int -> ReadS a
    readList :: ReadS [a]
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

In short, these are the standard "serialization" methods in Haskell.  `show :: (Show a) => a -> String` can turn anything that is an instance of `Show` into a string, and `read :: (Read a) => String -> a` can turn a string into anything that is an instance of `Read` (or throw an exception).

Most of the built-in types and data structures in the standard library have `Show` and `Read` instances defined; if you're composing parts from them, your type also has `Show` and `Read` instances defined.

```
type Table = [(String, String)]

load :: (Read a) => FilePath -> IO a
load f = do s <- readFile f
            return (read s)

save :: (Show a) => a -> FilePath -> IO ()
save x f = writeFile f (show x)
```

If `Table` were a datatype, you have to ask for the instances, but you can request that the compiler automatically derive them for you.

```
data Table = Table [(String, String)]
    deriving (Read, Show)
```

Sometimes that's not possible and you have to define your own instances.

```
instance Show Table where
    showsPrec p x = ...
instance Read Table where
    readsPrec p x = ...
```

But that shouldn't be common.

Answer (score 5):

The `show`/`read` approach will work fine, I use it as well, but only for small values. On larger, more complex values `read` will be very slow.

This contrived example demonstrates the bad performance of `read`:

```
data RevList a = (RevList a) :< a | Nil
  deriving (Show, Read)

ghci> read "(((((((((((((((Nil)))))))))))))))" :: RevList Int
```

Also, `read` won't be able to read some valid Haskell expressions, especially ones that use infix constructors (like the `:<` in my example). The reason for this is that `read` is unaware of the fixity of operators. This is also why `show $ Nil :< 1 :< 2 :< 3` will generate a lot of seemingly redundant parentheses.

If you want to have serialization for bigger values, I'd suggest to use some other library like [Data.Binary](http://code.haskell.org/binary/). This will be somewhat more complex than a simple `show`, mainly because of the lack of `deriving Binary`. However, there are various generic programming solutions to give you `deriving`-like surrogates.

**Conclusion:** I'd say, use the `show`/`read` solution until you reach its limits (probably once you start building actual applications), then start looking at something more scalable (but also more complex) like Data.Binary.

---

Side note: To those interested in parsers and more advanced Haskell stuff; The examples I gave came from the paper: [Haskel Do You Read Me?](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/pub/Center/TTTAS/paper-read.pdf), on an alternative, *fast* `read`-like function.

Comment: For deriving Binary, http://repetae.net/computer/haskell/DrIFT/ comes to mind.  That being said, it is certainly possible write smarter Read and Show instances for RevList in this simple case, and I agree that OP should stick to simple until scalability becomes an issue.

Answer (score 3):

With your current function you have a problem when the strings in the list contain "," or ")" because that makes it impossible to find out where a string ends when you try to read the data in again. You would need to escape these characters in some way whenever they appear in a string.

It's much easier to use [`show`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:show) and [`read`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:read) to convert your data to strings and back then to do it on your own:

```
save :: Table -> IO ()
save zs = writeFile "database.txt" (show zs)
```

`show` escapes special characters and makes sure the data is in a format that can be parsed by `read`. To load the data you would read the file into a string and pass this to `read` to convert it to your desired data structure.